# Kotlin REPL destructuring declarations is not working with Pair

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin and have written this sample code in the REPL.
The following code does not cause a crash.

```
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.1.0 (JRE 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
>>> val (a:String, b:Int) = Pair(1,2)
>>>
```

In Android Studio 2.3 the following code failed

```
val (a:String, b:Int) = Pair(1,2) // 'component1() function returns 'Int', but 'String' is expected
```

Is this a REPL bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `Int` is an `Int` and a `String` is a `String`; destructuring does not convert between types. As such, the code you have specified will not compile but the following will:

```
val (a: String, b: Int) = Pair("1", 2)
val (c: Int, d: Int) = Pair(3, 4)
```

Note that specifying the types explicitly is not necessary:

```
val (a, b) = Pair("1", 2)
val (c, d) = Pair(3, 4)
```

I am not certain why the REPL fails silently but the following in the REPL results in a "Unresolved reference" error so clearly the destructuring is not working but the REPL is not reporting such as an error. This appears to be a known issue: [KT-5620](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5620).

```
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.1.0 (JRE 1.8.0_111-b14)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit

val (a, b) = Pair(1, 2)
println(a) // Error: Unresolved reference: a
```